# Load a website in the background and once done redirect to the loaded website

Tags: javascript, python, php, node.js

I'm searching for a method to say:

```
<a href="http://example.com>click me</a>
<script>
If the <a> was clicked, don't redirect immediately, but instead, load http://example.com in the background, and once that is done, redirect the user to http://example.com
</script>
```

So this way, the user will wait inside my website, instead of waiting in the other website.

respectful right?

I know that the people will ask why do you want to do that. Please I'm just testing something..

What I think is: that it's maybe impossible using Javascript only, but I think that we can do it using some backend, I don't mind if you reply with nodejs or php, I like the more advanced boys.

Comment: I am not really into webdev, but I believe this is impossible because there is no such "load page in background" in browsers for security reasons obviously.

Comment: This is really an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What background and what exactly are you expecting to test?

Comment: Lol, I liked the xy problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So this way, the user will wait inside my website, instead of waiting in the other website.
> respectful right?

Doesn't sound like it to me.  People would likely rather see that next page loading.  You might be surprised to know that a lot of people don't have great internet connections, and can read the text of a site well before the rest of it loads.  Even if you could pull this off, you'd be breaking that behavior for them.

Fortunately, what you're asking to do isn't possible.  If you were in control of the site, you could use the Fetch API or AJAX to load content in the same page context, but that doesn't sound like it applies here.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot load example.com in background as browser which loads the example.com is on user side.

You could use a hidden div and load example.com into it and show that div once loading is completed but that would mean the user has not left your website at all.

As soon as hyperlink is clicked the browser starts their handshake with that other site and you lose the control of what happens between users browser and the server of example.com